# Truncate up to 8 characters, change to small words, remove special characters

Tags: php

email: `emDSDla.ccount@gmail.com`

```
<?php
$useruser = $customer->email; 
?>

<?php echo $useruser ?>
```

I need to create from customer email, I need to create username.

With rule:

- get only first 8 characters
- remove special characters @ .
- change to small words

**result:**

```
emdsdlac
```

Can anyone help me implement this to code?

**update:**

```
<?php   $useruserBIG = 'emDSDla.ccount@gmail.com'  ?>
    
<?php $resultsmall = strtolower($useruserBIG); ?>

<?php echo $resultsmall ?>

<?php 
$newstr = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\']/', '_', $resultsmall);
$newstr = str_replace("@", '', $resultsmall);

?>

<?php echo $newstr ?>
```

Currently I get result:

```
emdsdla.ccountgmail.com
```

Can anybody help me improve this code (merge in one  and correct with truncate) to get
**result:**

```
emdsdlac
```

Thanks!

**update3:**
currently I get correct result with this:

```
 <?php   $useruserBIG = 'emDSDla.ccount@gmail.com'  ?>
    
<?php $resultsmall = strtolower($useruserBIG); ?>


<?php 
$newstr = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\']/', '', $resultsmall);

?>

<?php echo substr($newstr, 0, 8) ?>
```

**result from above code:**

```
emdsdlac
```

The problem is, I cannot display in my script result some like this:

```
<?php echo substr($newstr, 0, 8) ?>
```

I can display result only with variable some like:

```
<?php $resultaftertruncate ?>
```

can anyone else help me to customize this code?

Comment: There is a php function for each of those operations; what have you tried so far? (Note you probably want to remove the non-alpha characters before you use `substr` to get the first eight.

Comment: `preg_replace`, `strtolower`, `substr`. Please try and update your post with the attempt. That said, if you have lots of users, chances are you will have collisions if you truncate to 8 characters.

Comment: @Markus AO, thank you for your hints. Can you please check my update?>

Comment: What you say you get doesn't add up. Simply the `strtolower` and `preg_replace` already get you to `emdsdla_ccount_gmail_com`. Replace with `''` instead of `'_'` if you don't want `.` and `@` etc. converted to underscores. Why do you want to keep `'` apostrophes? The `str_replace` is redundant after the regex. Then `substr($newstr, 0, 8)` and you're done.

Comment: Markus AO thanks for you help. I get result, which I want.  But I have one problem because I cannot display in my script result in echo with substr. I need to also first convert and then display only via variable example  <?php $resultaftertruncate ?>. Can you please give me any hint?

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. If you have a separate question about output, please feel free to ask a new question. (I notice your `<?php $result...` doesn't have an echo, so it won't output anything. Not sure what your trouble there is. )